# Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

---

### **I Can't Use This. How To Fix It.**

I make my projects for Obfuscator The Lua Script.

I make this for my script. I don't want other people to view my script.

Error:
`Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`
Code:

````
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using IronBrew2;
using IronBrew2.Obfuscator;

namespace IronBrew2_CLI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists("temp"))
                Directory.Delete("temp", true);
            Directory.CreateDirectory("temp");
            if (!IB2.Obfuscate("temp",  args[0], new ObfuscationSettings(), out string err))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERR: " + err);
                return;
            }

            File.Delete("out.lua");
            File.Move("temp/out.lua", "out.lua");
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: **https://github.com/DefCon42/ironbrew-2**
Project Link

Comment: Definitely would help if you included the line that caused the error...

Comment: Can you display `Console.WriteLine(args.Length)`?

Comment: Did you call the program with a command line argument? Otherwise `args[0]` will throw this exception, since you're trying to get the 0th (first) element of an empty array.